# Pass a sensitive variable value evaluated in one javascript file to another javascript file

Tags: javascript, variables, encryption, passwords, global

I have two HTML files each linked to different javascript files.

I am taking a user input in HTML file A and evaluating a variable x using javascript file A.

How do I display this variable x in HTML file B using javascript file b without having to repeat the evaluation I did in javascript file A

X is sensitive and hence I cannot use local storage or pass it as a string through the url.

Comment: You understand that the two JS files share the same global namespace right?

Comment: So if it is evaluated once, I can just use it in JS file 2?

Comment: If the value, that is calculated by script A is dependent on user input, you cannot just include script A on page B. So, you'd need to send the value somehow between those two pages. If the two pages are open at the same time in the same browser in different tabs/windows, you could use something like `window.postMessage`, but that can be spied on by extensions and such. Anyway, if you're using JavaScript, you need to rethink your approach and justification why something is sensitive. Just localStorage is perfectly fine. You need to formulate your requirements clearly for you and for us.